# How do you use variables of one method in another method of a different class?

Tags: java

I want to know if I can use the variables `user2` and `pass2` (which are both located in the `showWindow()` method in class `Register`) to the `showWindow()` method in class `LoginDemo` so that the username and password that gets inputted in the `Register` class will match the input in the `LoginDemo` class.

```
public class LoginDemo 

    public static void showWindow() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Log in/Sign up ");
        frame.setSize(300, 180);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        userLabel = new JLabel("USERNAME");
        userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);

        userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
        panel.add(userText);

        passwordLabel = new JLabel("PASSWORD");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
        passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        button = new JButton("LOG-IN");
        button.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        button.addActionListener(new LoginDemo());
        panel.add(button);

        success = new JLabel("");
        success.setBounds(10, 110, 300, 25);
        panel.add(success);

        JButton registerButton = new JButton("CREATE ACCOUNT");
        registerButton.setBounds(130, 80, 150, 25);
        panel.add(registerButton);
        registerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                Register w2 = new Register();
                w2.showWindow();
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        Register w2 = new Register();

        String user = userText.getText();
        String password = passwordText.getText();


        if(user.equals(w2.user2) && password.equals(w2.pass2))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Log in Successful!");
        }
        else
        {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Login Details" + " \nLogin Error ");
        }

    }
}
```

```
public class Register
 

        label1 = new JLabel("Username");
        label1.setBounds(20, 50, 100, 20);
        frame.add(label1);

        t1 = new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(130, 50, 100, 20);
        frame.add(t1);

        label2 = new JLabel("Password");
        label2.setBounds(20, 100, 100, 20);
        frame.add(label2);

        t2 = new JPasswordField();
        t2.setBounds(130, 100, 100, 20);
        frame.add(t2);

        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.setBounds(70, 350, 80, 20);
        frame.add(submit);
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                LoginDemo w1 = new LoginDemo();
                String user2 = t1.getText();
                String pass2 = t2.getText();
                w1.showWindow();
                frame.setVisible(false);


            }
        });



        back = new JButton("Back");
        back.setBounds(250, 350, 80, 20);
        frame.add(back);
        back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                LoginDemo w1 = new LoginDemo();
                w1.showWindow();
                frame.setVisible(false);



            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: You can't, there's a thing called "scope". What you can do is pass these values to the constructor of Register class. Also you might wanna learn about "encapsulation".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it through the constructor of the Login class.
add a constructor to the login class.

```
public class LoginDemo {
   private String user2, pass2;
   public LoginDemo(String user2, String pass2) {
       this.user2 = user2;
       this.pass2 = pass2;
   }
```

now in your register class just pass the values

```
LoginDemo w1 = new LoginDemo(user2, pass2);
```

and in Register class you can access it by `this.user2` and `this.pass2`